# How to get the numeric exit status of an exited docker container?

Tags: docker, exit-code

When a container exits, `docker ps -a` shows its exit code (scroll

```
$ docker run ubuntu bash -c "exit 1"
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE    COMMAND              CREATED        STATUS                     PORTS                     NAMES
c2c769c4b9ef   ubuntu   "bash -c 'exit 1'"   6 seconds ago  Exited (1) 3 seconds ago                             happy_fermat
```

**How do I get the numeric exit code programmatically, without error-prone `grep`-ing and `cut`-ing?**

Answer (score 54):

Use [`docker inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) with templates:

```
$ docker inspect c2c769c4b9ef --format='{{.State.ExitCode}}'
1
```

Comment: Be advised that this answer may be deceptive in some cases. Check mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75836395/2886980

Comment: Be careful. If your container is not designed to exit like the question and "hangs", you can see running container has an ExitCode. See also, https://stackoverflow.com/q/77296413/20307768

Answer (score 28):

You can use `echo`:

```
$ docker run debian bash -c "exit 1"
$ echo $?
1

$ docker run debian bash -c "exit 0"
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: "$? Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline." - if you were wondering what "$?" does - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/501128/what-does-echo-do/501129

Answer (score 22):

The [exit status of `docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#exit-status) is the exit status of the contained command, except if there is a problem with Docker itself (in which case the status is 125) or the contained command could not be invoked (in which case the status is 126) or could not be invoked (in which case the status is 127).

Therefore when you execute `docker run` as a child process, you can retrieve the exit status as you would for any other child process:

- In a C or C++ program, or other programming language giving access to the POSIX API, using [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).
- In a POSIX like shell (which in practice means most Unix shells, including `bash`), as the content of the special `$?` variable *immediately after* completion of a `docker run`.
- In Java, the value of [`Process.exitValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue()) for the `Process` you used to do `docker run`.

If you are using a Docker API, it should provide access to the exit status.

- In Java using the [Spotify Docker client](https://github.com/spotify/docker-client), the value of `ContainerExit.statusCode()` of the `ContainerExit` object returned by `docker.waitContainer()`.

Answer (score 6):

Be advised that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46300611/2886980
may be somewhat deceptive.

As for Docker version 20.10.23 commad:

```
$ docker inspect c2c769c4b9ef --format={{.State.ExitCode}}
```

will return 0 for running containers as well for those that exited with code 0.

This is not very reasonable. I would expect that command returns empty string for running containers. Otherwise it is impossible to tell containers successfully finished from those still running.

It means that if you are not sure if the container **has exited**, code 0 may get you in trouble.

Better option for such case is:

```
$ docker inspect c2c769c4b9ef --format={{.State.Status}}:{{.State.ExitCode}}
```

Result will be:

```
running:0
```

or

```
exited:0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```bash
docker wait c2c769c4b9ef
```

If the container is already stopped, you directly get the exit code.