# Docker-inspect .State.Running's exit status test always fails

Tags: bash, docker, continuous-integration, podman

I'm currently writing SIGTERM, SIGINT python code to exit gracefully. (which means it doesn't exit immediately and hangs now)

So I wrote a test.

Because docker-inspect's `.State.ExitCode`  is **sometimes** deceptive (https://stackoverflow.com/a/75836395/20307768),

This is my case (`"Running": true,` and  `"ExitCode": 0`)

```
               "Running": true,
               "Paused": false,
               "Restarting": false,
               "OOMKilled": false,
               "Dead": false,
               "Pid": 206346,
               "ConmonPid": 206344,
               "ExitCode": 0,
```

**I'm using `.State.Running` of the test container before checking the container exit status.**

```
docker inspect --format '{{json .State.Running}}' $test-container
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    exit 1
fi
```

**This code always fails.
What should I do?**

Answer (score 0):

To who is using **the exit status** of `docker inspect --format="{{.State.Running}}"` to test, **Don't**.

`docker inspect --format="{{.State.Running}}" $ALIVE_CONTAINER; echo $?`

`docker inspect --format="{{.State.Running}}" $STOPPED_CONTAINER; echo $?`

**Both are ZERO. (Podman shows the same result.)**

I saw exit status other than 0 because `docker inspect --format="{{.State.Running}}" $NONEXISTENT_NAME; echo $?`

**Rather do it like this**

like [Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/343944/546660)'s answer.

```
return=$(docker inspect --format="{{.State.Running}}" -q $test-container)

#the $return is true string or false string
```

or
if you really want to use exit status,

```
docker inspect --format="{{.State.Running}}" $test-container | grep 'true'
#or grep 'false'
# both GNU or BSD grep returns 0 as a exit status if the line was selected
# EXIT STATUS section of https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?grep
# https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html
```